# D-Bus Send variant via d-feet

Tags: debugging, dbus

I use D-Feet D-Bus debugger to investigate some interfaces.
One of them requires a `variant` type to be send as an argument (which means that you can send anything).

But I have trouble sending the argument as `variant` - normal python syntax would be `__import__('dbus').Boolean(0)` for a boolean, but that won't work (`Error.InvalidArguement`).

Using `variant:boolean:0` doesn't work either.

How to send a arguement as `variant` via D-Feet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried `__import__('dbus').Boolean(0, variant_level=1)` and it seems that it worked.

Answer (score 25):

In d-feet 0.3.9 at least, `GLib.Variant('b', False)` works.

Comment: I'd like ti give you +200 for that. Using d-feet 0.3.3 and it works well.

Comment: @ptomato If it is something like `GetTask (variant tid) ----> ()`, how does it work in that case?

Comment: I don't know what `GetTask` is; maybe you should open a new question?

Comment: Ugh, thank you for that! I tried every conceivable permutation of the text representation(s) used by dconf, since the argument format seemed to generally follow them, but I was banging against a wall trying to send a variant. (Of, as in your example, a single boolean value. Sigh. What ever happened to 1 and 0? *mumbledrone*) We should really pass the hat or something and get d-feet a real Help file, because what's there now is... sad. Just so very, very sad.